# Radio button checked by default - JQuery event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a radio button already clicked in html, and I need some help figuring out how to apply the event in JQuery for the already clicked button. 
Right now, if the button is already clicked there is no event happening, but if i click again it does what it's supposed to do.
I have 2 radio buttons, the first one is already clicked for a message in a div to be hidden, is the second radio is checked then the message with show. I have problems implementing the already clicked radio.
This is the html:

```
<label for="answer">Answers:</label><input type="radio" name="type" value="Yes/No" class="answers" checked="checked" id="answer"><span> Yes/No Form </span> <br><input type="radio" name="type1" value="Multiple" class="move"> <span>Multiple choice form </span><br>
```

And this is the JQuery so far:

```
$(".answers").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("div.desc").hide();
}); 

$(".move").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("div.desc").show();
});
```

If anyone can please help, thank you!

Comment: Id use `.change` for `input` toggles.

Comment: What @tymeJV and just run the portion of code for the one already clicked outside of your method as well. This will entail it runs one time and because it is already checked.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/change/ This is what @tymeJV means

Comment: Maybe i'm not clearly understanding what it is you're wanting, but it sounds like you want the `div` to be hidden on page load?

Comment: @RhapX - Yes, I want it to be hidden at the beggining.

Comment: @tymeJV - I got the idea about the .change function, but I don't know how to implement it and actually work.

Comment: @FirebladeDan - I see, but I dont know how to make de .change function work for me.

Comment: @Kyuubido0 see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are multiple option to hide $("div.desc") at the time of page :

1). at the time of DOM ready just call a trigger event, it will fire a click event like:

```
$(".answers").trigger("click")
```

OR

2). just add a simple condition to explicitly hide the content on page load like:

```
$("div.desc").hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are wanting to hide the `div` on page load, just utilize CSS.

Add a `display` to your CSS class:

```
div.desc {
    display: none;
}
```

Or to the `div` element itself.

`<div class="desc" style="display: none;">omg</div>`

This will hide the element on page load, allowing you to show/hide the form as needed.

For completeness, here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jackpb16/).

Comment: Thank you so much! <3
It works now!
I didn't even think about css!

Comment: @Kyuubido0 no problem, glad to help :)

Comment: I have the exact same undesired symptoms as OP, and already have the `display: none` CSS applied to the class. How unfortunate it seems to work for everyone else